# How to improve performance when I have millions of records in one table?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables.

### inventories

This is where I have millions of records and that is continuously growing every night. Each inventory is assigned with a unique code

It has around 50 columns.

Now here is the thing, we have another table:

### save_these_inventories

We match the unique code here with the above inventories table. If it is matched then we download the whole record into "save_these_inventories" table.

from Table A -> records goes to Table B

However it takes so much of time to first search into inventories table where it has to match with the unique code through millions of records. If it is found then import into "save_these_inventories" table.

Then we put these items on the dashboard, Of course on dashboard page then it loads faster because it loads from "save_these_inventories" after importing of record. which has less rows

However I am thinking to change the way it is working now, but not sure if it will increase the performance or decrease it.

Here is my approach. Instead of importing everything to "save_these_inventories" table why don't I just match the uniquecode and assign the unique to "save_these_inventories". Then instead of importing, use the inner join to fetch the data without importing?

But I am thinking then on dashboard it will take forever to load the data since it will have to search through the millions of records for every user?

What will be best approach to handle this?

Comment: I would observe that a table with 50 columns is a little unusual.

Comment: May we see a sample of the data? It sounds like it could do with some normalisation.

Comment: If you're less interested in older data - especially if to the extent of deleting older data - then you might also look at range partitioning.

Comment: @halfer, nothing related to normalization since it has independent table and works with matching of unique code with the other table then import to another table. i am annoyed of importing.

Comment: I still think it would be useful for you to show a sample row.